# Power lost in second gear

Tags: vehicle-speed-sensor

Moved car off in first , engaged second and no power .limped back home ,left car and tried it again 2 days later .Power seems ok now in all gears ..any advice ps it was particularly cold that day and car wasn't used for more than 24 hours..thanks

Comment: Tell us which vehicle you have, make, model, engine.  Is it an automatic or manual?

Comment: While you were limping back home, was the engine revving higher than normal, or was the engine struggling to rev?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure you didn't by accident put it into 4th gear instead of 2nd? Not knowing the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle doesn't help, as some vehicles are prone to loose shifters where this type of thing happens relatively easily.

Comment: Fiesta st line 2020 plate... didn't put it into 4th.. manual transmission limped home in first 20 mph revs normal,just no power when I put it into second do stopped n put it back into first.now 3 days later all seems ok but don't want to drive it

Comment: Ford fiesta 2020 plate.. engine reving ok but kept it in first to get home